# Laravel blade pages do not load completely in some time

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, html, laravel-blade

[The highlighted parts are jquery, whose complete code is in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3YLU.png). Not only jquery some time also the html tags load in-completely and need to refresh from time to time]

If all html tags, blade syntax and jquery load fine the web page is displayed correctly.

If anything is not being loaded out, need to refresh again :(

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su3nE.png)--image jquery not loaded completely ---
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3YLU.png)--- jquery code ---

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".loader").fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i removed all internal and external jquery, though the same problem :(

Comment: you need to add jquery library. and always need to use jQuery(document).ready(......, without jquery you can't use 'jQuery' or '$'